# CSS - Padding affecting background image on DIV

Tags: css, html

I have a div like this:

```
<div id="mybox">Hello World</div>
```

and the CSS for this is:

```
#mybox {
    position:absolute;
    left:30px;
    top:147px;
    width:556px;
    height:31px;
    font-family : Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size : 24px;
    color: white;
        background-image:url('images/image2.jpg');
    background-repeat:no;
    text-align:left;
    vertical-align:middle;
        text-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #000;
}
```

Like I said, this div has a text inside. In this example: "hello world".

But I think the text is too close to the left border and I would like to add a little padding to the div. So I have added this

```
padding-left:5px;
```

the problem is that by doing so, the div's image moves to the right and covers another div that is to the right.

How can I move the text 5 pixels to the right and keep the div's image fixed?

thanks.

Comment: If you had `box-sizing:border-box` on, adding padding wouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you must use `text-indent`

FROM http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/text-indent

> margins and padding affect the whole block, text-indent only applies
>   to the first rendered line of text in the element.

Your css with `text-indent`

```
#mybox {
    position:absolute;
    left:30px;
    top:147px;
    width:556px;
    height:31px;
    font-family : Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size : 24px;
    color: white;
        background-image:url('images/image2.jpg');
    background-repeat:no;
    text-align:left;
    vertical-align:middle;
        text-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #000;
    text-indent:100px;
}
```

check this [working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/D7Z74/)

**important note**:

From http://css-plus.com/2010/09/best-of-css-plus/

> If you have a set width of 200px and then add a 20px left padding, the
>   total element size would be 220px. It’s possible to solve this problem
>   by changing the width to 180px, but I find this very annoying as the
>   width has to be changed every time the padding is changed. Text-indent
>   solves this absolutely wonderfully.

Comment: PERFECT! Worked perfectly! THANKS!!!!! Is there any equivalent to this to create indents in all directions?

Answer (score 2):

You should add position to your background image:

```
background-image: url('images/image2.jpg');
background-position: left top;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

Comment: unfortunately, after testing more, this solution is causing other problems on the divs around...

Answer (score 0):

Edit : 
Padding Work fine , you can checkout it in this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/6HxJ4/
I just add a border to show what's the borders line .
`padding-left:50px;`

Comment: Nope, margin moves the whole div. Margin is something outside the div.

Comment: checkout the jsfiddle link

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
padding-left:5px;
background-position: -5px 0px;
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would be to wrap your text in another element, and give that element a left-margin of 5 pixels, like so:

```
<div id="mybox">
    <p>Hello World</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
p {
     margin-left:5px;
}
```

Putting a margin on the div itself will not move the text around within the box.

Answer (score 0):

*Late-to-the-party response...*

This can be addressed by CSS [background-origin](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-origin.asp).

As noted by w3schools...

```
background-origin: padding-box|border-box|content-box|initial|inherit;
```

- **padding-box** -- The background image starts from the upper left corner of the padding edge.
- **border-box** -- The background image starts from the upper left corner
  of the border.
- **content-box**  -- The background image starts from the upper left corner of the content.

In this example...

```
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;

padding-left: 20px;
padding-top: 40px;

background-origin: padding-box;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: 20px 10px;
background-size: 22px 22px;
background-image: url(../artwork/image.png);
```

...the text and image are flush left at 20 pixels, with the image placed 20 pixels from the top of the div, and the text starting 40 pixels from the top.